# Issue of title of beamer slide (while maintaining enumerate)

Tags: beamer, page-breaking, enumerate

I am dealing with beamer now in second slide I am using `enumerate` and list of items is very large. I wish to maintain item number in next slide that is why I am applying `\framebreak`. But the main issue is title of slide is changed by `Introduction I` to `Introduction II`, you can see this after compiling.

How to solve this problem?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{default}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
\usepackage{setspace}
%\setstretch{1.0}change this number as per requirement
%\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{1em}} % increase
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-0.4em}} % decrease
%make new line after item
\makeatletter
\def\myitem{%
    \@ifnextchar[ \@myitem{\@noitemargtrue\@myitem[\@itemlabel]}}
\def\@myitem[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}\\}
\makeatother
%make new line after item
\title[title]{\textbf{xyz}}
\author[my self]{}
\date[\today]{}
\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}[t]{\textbf{Outline}}
        \setstretch{2.0}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Introduction
            \item B
            \item C
            \item D
            \item E
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
        \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]{\textbf{Introduction}}
        %\setstretch{1.50}
        \textbf{Properties}

        \vspace{0.35cm}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \setlength\itemsep{0.9em}
            \item \textbf{P-1} \mbox{}\\
            Text
            \item \textbf{P-2} \mbox{}\\
            Text
            \item \textbf{P-3} \mbox{}\\
            Text
            \item \textbf{P-4} \mbox{}\\
            Text
            \item \textbf{P-5} \mbox{}\\
            Text\framebreak
            \item 
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][]
```

The manual says

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{default}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
\usepackage{setspace}
%\setstretch{1.0}change this number as per requirement
%\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{1em}} % increase
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-0.4em}} % decrease
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][]
%make new line after item
\makeatletter
\def\myitem{%
    \@ifnextchar[ \@myitem{\@noitemargtrue\@myitem[\@itemlabel]}}
\def\@myitem[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}\\}
\makeatother
%make new line after item
\title[title]{\textbf{xyz}}
\author[my self]{}
\date[\today]{}
\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}[t]{\textbf{Outline}}
        \setstretch{2.0}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Introduction
            \item B
            \item C
            \item D
            \item E
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
        \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{\textbf{Introduction}}
        %\setstretch{1.50}
        \textbf{Properties}

        \vspace{0.35cm}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \setlength\itemsep{0.9em}
            \item \textbf{P-1} \mbox{}\\
            Text
            \item \textbf{P-2} \mbox{}\\
            Text
            \item \textbf{P-3} \mbox{}\\
            Text
            \item \textbf{P-4} \mbox{}\\
            Text
            \item \textbf{P-5} \mbox{}\\
            Text\framebreak
            \item 
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing information.